# list changing with javascript

Tags: javascript, mootools, innerhtml, html-lists

I'm using MooTools.

I have a `ul` element:

```
<ul id="alerts"></ul>
```

And I can access it with `$("alerts")`, but when I try to change it by doing:

```
$("alerts").innerHTML += "<li>word</li>";
```

In a `for` loop, it only does the first... It doesn't add any more `li` tags. Full code here: `rightandrong.info/Upload.html`. I've modified it so it doesn't actually upload.

Drag and drop multiple files, and it should tell you when each one is done in the `ul`. What's wrong?

EDIT: Checking the full code is recommended.

Comment: For the love of god, don't put `$("alerts").innerHTML += "<li>word</li>";` within a for loop!

Comment: Why not...? I just need to append `li` elements after each upload!

Comment: innerHTML as string is immutable, this is a terrible idea. use a fragment and new Element instead...

Comment: Yh Dimitar, but if u do it once (after a loop i.e.) it's not that terrible btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That's why you can't do it](http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/SL39m/)

Regarding your problem: on the js fiddle I did it's working, are you sure the loop contains something more than one element? (on your example it's working too)

Comment: Have you checked the length of the array you're looping after dropping files?

Comment: `files.length` == number of files im dropping

Comment: Is that `if (xhr.readyState == 4)` evaluated to true each time?? Just put a console.log inside, before that innerHTML.. and see what happens :), and set the html at the end of the loop!